# Who is user 19341?

Tags: discussion, community

I asked the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232057/who-is-user-19341) at Stack Exchange Meta, and I think it is also good to ask the question here.

I found that Google Chrome omnibox suggests me "english stackexchange users 19341" when I search for "English stac".

This is interesting; who is this "users 19341", and more importantly, what is he doing so much with English SE that **0he/she is given special status by Google search?**

[image]

Comment: 19341 is your rep on Stack Overflow minus your user IDs on SO, MSE, SU and Proggers, the top four sites you participate in. No seriously, that is the only answer I can guess at, and here's twenty roubles saying this guess is better than any other, including Google's very own.

Comment: Way back in January, user [Mahnax](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/11550/mahnax) posted [Yes, if you Google "english.stackexchange.com/users/19341" then it will tell you who it is.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95/2013/1/31/19-21) in ELU chat. Perhaps a lot of people actually *did* that, and Google automatically biased its predictive text accordingly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think that's a great comment! Would you like to make it into an answer? I'll love to accept it!

Comment: Google's indexes only retain **deleted** content for a short time, so since user19341 was deleted some time ago, that method no longer works. (Side issue: this is why the recent EU Supreme Court ruling is so perverse. Force an index entry to be expunged, but leave the content itself intact. Why not force the deletion of the obsolete content itself, and then the index self-updates.)

Comment: It could be that Graviton googled for that user at one time, or selected that user's profile link, right? Because I don't get it in my predictive text.

Comment: @KitFox: Nah. I'd definitely never googled **"english stackexchange users 19341"** before I saw this, and it's vanishingly unlikely I'd ever have typed the first two words in before (I know even if I *was* searching for those two words, I'd enter them in the opposite sequence). But like OP, I got the same "autocomplete" after entering just **"English stac"** (but for me it's the third choice after "english stackexchange" and "english stack overflow", and I don't get offered the possibility of "stackexchange english questions").